# Refactoring or Renaming Class Imports in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, uima, automated-refactoring

In my eclipse project I have dependencies that are imported like this:

```
import org.uimafit.util.JCasUtil;
```

However, there has been a namespace change in my dependent project (it moved to apache) such that I need to refactor these imports to look more like this:

```
import org.apache.uima.fit.JCasUtil;
```

I am using:

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Mars.2 Release
>   (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600

Is there any way to automatically refactor all instances of imports of this type in Eclipse? Answers that include plugins, upgrading/changing my version of Eclipse are all acceptable.

Comment: Why not just use Search/replace? That string is pretty specific and unlikely to be there in any context that doesn't need replacement, isn't it?

Comment: There are several classes I need to change, but yes, I agree it is pretty specific and using wildcards should suffice. I think I got so spoiled by refactoring variable names using "refactor" I just expected there to be something similar for imports. But it is really not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Search --> File`, the search dialog will pop up.

In the `containing text` text-field type the string you want to replace: `import org.uimafit.util.JCasUtil;`

In the `File name patterns` type `*.java` (the files you want to look into).

Then hit the `Replace` button. It will find the text and another dialog will pop up, titled `Replace text matches`. In the `With` text field, type the new text: `import org.apache.uima.fit.JCasUtil;` and hit the `OK` button. It will replace all the matches.

Comment: I'd drop the `import` from the search and use only the fully qualified class name, because there can be spaces, tabs, etc. between the two. And if there is an odd occurrence of the fully qualified class name which is not in an import, it probably should be replaced as well.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense. In my case I didn't have any of those fully qualified class names so it didn't matter, but your answer is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, you can create a package named `org.uimafit.util` and then you create all the classes referred to by your imports: `JCasUtil`, etc.

Then open the package explorer view > right-click on the package `org.uimafit.util` > Refactor > Rename > enter `org.apache.uima.fit` > and press the "OK" button.

Removed the `org.apache.uima.fit` package from your project and you are done.